# Want to retrieve data from files located within a SharePoint folder path

Tags: web-scraping, sharepoint, python-requests, html-parsing, python-requests-html

We're currently attempting to retrieve data from files located within a SharePoint folder. We're utilizing `requests_ntlm` for authentication, which successfully returns a 200 response.

However, we're encountering difficulties in extracting the filenames or data contained within files in the folder path from the `response.content`. We're utilizing `BeautifulSoup()` to parse the content and extract the necessary data from the files within the folder path.

We'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions you could offer to improve the code for fetching data from the files within the SharePoint folder path.

code snippet:

[image]

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_excel_files(sharepoint_folder_link, username, password):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
    response = session.get(sharepoint_folder_link)
    excel_files = []
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.content)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        #all_links= re.findall(link_pattern, str(soup))
        regex = "https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\\+.~#?&\\/=]*)"
        all_links = re.findall(regex, str(soup))
        #print([x[0] for x in all_links])
        print("all_links")
        print(all_links)
        for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            href = link['href']
            if href.endswith('.xlsx'):
                excel_files.append(href)
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data from {sharepoint_folder_link}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    return excel_files
 
def main():
    sharepoint_folder_link = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    excel_files = fetch_excel_files(sharepoint_folder_link, username, password)
    if excel_files:
        print("Excel files found:")
        for file_url in excel_files:
            session = requests.Session()
            session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
            response = session.get(file_url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(response.content))
                for ws in wb.worksheets:
                    print("Worksheet:", ws.title)
                    for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                        text = ' '.join(str(cell) for cell in row if cell)
                        pii_info = check_patterns(text)
                        if pii_info:
                            print("PII found in row:", pii_info)
            else:
                print(f"Failed to retrieve the file. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    else:
        print("No Excel files found.")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

we did try parse the data using HTML parsing, where we expected `response.content` to return the data from files that are under the folder path but it is giving us HTML structure without any links or filenames.

Comment: Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, considering the time constraints I'm facing.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?